# toggle the value of anchor tag and pass it to the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to pass the value on or off in the ajax url as trans. Right now the text of  is toggled .But the trans in url is not updated based on the on and off values . Any help?I need to reload the page since I am setting and unsetting something in my code  based on this on and off value..So when the link value is "on" the value on should be passed in url and excecute he actions based on that ..otherwise the actions based on off..In the console it only displays the "on" value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#trans_flag').click(function() {
    
                      var trans = $('#trans_flag').text() ;
                      //var trans=$(this).val();
                      if(trans=='on')
                      {
                          $('#trans_flag').text("off")
                          trans='on';
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          $('#trans_flag').text("on")
                          trans='off';
                      }
                      var base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
                      $.ajax
                      ({
                          'type': 'POST',
                          'url': base_url + 'translation/language/searchUntranslated/'+trans,
                          'success': function(response){
                              window.location.reload();
                              alert(trans);
                              console.log(response);
                          }
                      });
    
                  });
                  });
              </script>
    <a  id='trans_flag' name='trans_flag'>on</a>
```

Comment: The lines where you reassign a value to trans are superfluous as trans already has the same value than the one which you reassign.

Comment: Why do you reload the page? That is going to reset all the code... and if {"on"} { setting "off" and "on" } Refreshing the page, the code resets back to the original so unless your serverside code is updating the state, you will be back to square one.  ANd the code after the reload ain't going to run/

Comment: ^^ don't reload, put the data in place!

Comment: `trans` is not getting passed in url at all or its not passing with updated value ?

Comment: trans is not passing with updated value

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage to maintain state `on` and `off` after reloading page.Try in your local as `Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window'` here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getTrans(){
      var trans = localStorage.getItem('trans');
        if(trans !=null){
          if(trans == 'on'){
            $('#trans_flag').text("off");
            localStorage.setItem('trans', 'off');
          }else{
            $('#trans_flag').text("on");
            localStorage.setItem('trans', 'on');
          }
        }else{
            trans = 'on';
            $('#trans_flag').text("on");
            localStorage.setItem('trans', 'on');
        }
        return trans;
    }
    $('#trans_flag').click(function() {
        var trans = getTrans();
        var base_url = 'base_url/';
        console.log(base_url + 'translation/language/searchUntranslated/'+trans);
    });
    getTrans();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  id='trans_flag' name='trans_flag'></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove alert(trans)Form the code ajax request

```
 $.ajax
                  ({
                      'type': 'POST',
                      'url': base_url + 'translation/language/searchUntranslated/'+trans,
                      'success': function(response){
                          window.location.reload();
                          //alert(trans);
                          console.log(response);
                      }
                  });
```

Comment: The trans value in url is not still updatng  .It dispalys only the actions based on the "on"value.